# Convert UNIX timestamp to string

Tags: javascript, polymer, epoch

I'm using Polymer and I have a date as a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 1487016105201) that I want to format as `mm/dd/yyyy - hh/mm`.

I resolved the problem...   see below:

```
<vaadin-grid-column>
  <template class="header">BINTS01 - last scan</template>
  <!--<template>[[item.BINTS01]]</template>  this works-->
  <template>[[_formatEpochDate(item.BINTS01)]]</template>
</vaadin-grid-column>
```

The `<script>` section is:

```
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-view8',
  properties:{
      eTS : String,
      },
  _formatEpochDate: function(eTS){
      // return eTS
      var d = new Date(eTS);
      var n = d.getUTCDay();
      return d.toDateString()
       },        
});
```

Comment: Your property's name is `eTS` but in you're template you're calling `_formatEpochDate(item.BINTS01)`. What is `item.BINTS01`?

Comment: item.BINTS01 is an array field.   But I don't think that is the issue.  I think its just a matter of converting that value... which is in epoch form, into a date string.  this code works... just returns the epoch and not the date .

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two reasons why `Date(eTS).toUTC` isn't working.

1. Calling `Date` as a function (i.e. `Date(eTS)` without `new`) returns a string, not a Date object. You want `new Date(eTS)`.
2. Neither Strings nor Date objects have a property named `toUTC` (nor do they have a method named `toUTC`, so `toUTC()` won't work either). Maybe you meant [`toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)?

With the above facts in mind, you could change your code to this:

```js
function _formatEpochDate(eTS) {
  return new Date(eTS).toUTCString();
}

const dateString = _formatEpochDate(1487016105201);
console.log(dateString);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

...but that doesn't give you your desired format. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString):

> The value returned by `toUTCString()` is a human readable string in the UTC time zone. The format of the return value may vary according to the platform. The most common return value is a RFC-1123 formatted date stamp, which is a slightly updated version of RFC-822 date stamps.

There are a variety of ways you could solve this, including writing your own date formatter. Another option is to use a library like [strftime](https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime), as below:

```js
function _formatEpochDate(eTS) {
  return strftime('%D - %H:%M', new Date(eTS));
}

const dateString = _formatEpochDate(1487016105201);
console.log(dateString);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/strftime@0.10.0/strftime-min.js"></script>
```